# Should an "ancient" question that would be rejected now be nominated for closing?

Tags: discussion, scope, vote-to-close

[This seven year old question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/should-i-use-and-loop-or-just-a-loop) was recently edited to update some of the links in it.

However, this question would nowadays be rejected as not-reviewable code. Should such old questions be nominated for closing if we encounter them?

On other SEs such questions are sometimes locked with the notification that they're technically off-topic, but are preserved for history's sake (or something along those lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Just vote to close

I don't see a compelling historical value to this question.

So no need to lock and keep; just treat it the same as any newer question.

Comment: Actively going out and closing questions because the rules have changed can come across as hostile to askers that never did anything wrong. Your answer is unclear on how to treat _all_ "ancient" questions and can be interpreted as encouraging people to actively go out and close old questions.

Comment: Yes, Vogel's answer says that.  This meta question was specifically about recently-edited (so now visible in Recent Questions) posts.

Comment: The title is very generic and doesn't include that assumption.

Answer (score 2):

There is something to be said about handling questions that get resurfaced "organically" vs. actively seeking out older questions and flagging / closing them. Since this question was surfaced by an edit (albeit one that was triggered through some tool assistance), I would want to evaluate the question according to the current standards.

It's not productive to sift through **all** the "old" questions on site to check whether they are still on-topic. It's also not really productive to ignore old and off-topic questions that became active recently, just because they are old.

In summary I'd say: Vote to close if you happen across a question like that, but don't actively look for such questions.